# How to prevent double click event in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am new in Jquery and i know lot of similar Post are there on same but its not working in my situation don't know why? Any way let me explain My scenario I am calling drop down bind method on grid click event and i want to call only one time i Tried like this. Please help me

```
$(function () {
            $("[id*=dgDepots]").one('click', function () {
                BindLocationsHeader();
            });
        });
```

**Function**

```
function BindLocationsHeader(data, status) {

    if (alldata != undefined && alldata.Locations != undefined) {
        var divisionCode = $('#ddlDivision').val();
        var regionCode = $('#ddlRegion').val();
        $('#ddlLocationH').empty();
        d = alldata.Locations;
        $("[id$='ddlLocationH']").append($("<option>select</option>").val("0").html("Select"));
        for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            if (divisionCode == d[i].DivisionCode && regionCode == d[i].RegionCode) {
                var ddlVal = d[i].LocationCode;
                var ddlText = d[i].LocationName;
                $("[id$='ddlLocationH']").append($("<option ExchangeRate='" + d[i].ExchangeRate + "' NoOfDecimals='" + d[i].NoOfDecimals + "' CurrencyCode='" + d[i].CurrencyCode + "' >select</option>").val(ddlVal).html(ddlText));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Grid View

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgDepots" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="grid"
        Width="100%"
        OnRowDeleting="dgDepots_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgDepots_RowInserting" OnRowUpdating="dgDepots_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="LocationCode" VisibleIndex="0">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <%--<select id="ddlLocation" name="ddlLocation" class="width50p input-tb"></select>--%>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocationH" class="width50p input-tb" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;<span><img src="/Images/icon_required_field.gif" /></span>

                </EditItemTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="CostCenterCode" VisibleIndex="1">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <%--<select id="ddlCostCenterCode" name="ddlCostCenterCode" class="width50p input-tb"></select>--%>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCostCenterCode" class="width50p input-tb" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;<span><img src="/Images/icon_required_field.gif" /></span>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="GLCode" VisibleIndex="2">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <%-- <select id="ddlGLCode" name="ddlGLCode" class="width50p input-tb"></select>--%>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGLCode" class="width50p input-tb" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;<span><img src="/Images/icon_required_field.gif" /></span>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
            <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" VisibleIndex="2">
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>


        </Columns>
```

On this grid click i want to populate drop down list value which i can do same using above code but unable to prevent double click event

But drop down is not binding in this situation and there is no any error appearing on console.
Can any one help me on same

Comment: Does `$("[id*=dgDepots]")` match anything?

Comment: its grid view ID on grid view click i am binding all function

Comment: That's not what I asked, :)  Your intention is for it to match something.  But does it actually?

Comment: So you need to figure out what about your selector is not matching the element(s)

Comment: @Taplar So for that what i need to check where can i check ? can you please suggest me

Comment: You have to check the html elements that have the ids on them, and figure out why your selector is not matching them.

Comment: @Taplar But while debugging i can see its hitting to click event that menase all ids are correctly binded ryt?

Comment: What does that mean?  You said your selector was not matching anything.  If it is not matching anything, then your event handler will never execute.

Comment: @Taplar I don't understand "not matching anything" what you are asking about, but as i can see while debugging on browser i can see break point is hitting on click event It means all Control IDS are correct Please guide me if i am wrong